# OS is not letting me save my code, why is this happening?

Tags: python

Background:
I'm trying to code a program that changes the starting value of a variable in the same program when it's done. In the process, I was trying to save the code below and it wouldn't save. I'm using Python Idle 3.8.5

Code:

```
test = 45

write = open("test file change in file.py", "w")
with open("test file change in file.py", "r") as read:
    file = read.read()

write.write(file)
write.close()
```

Question:
Why is it not saving?

Comment: You are opening the file for both reading and writing at the same time.  I don't know what that will do, but you shouldn't be doing that.  Move the first `open()` down two lines and your code should then rewrite the file.  Of course, you'll need to change the value of `file` to see any change to the file.  As it is now, `test` isn't being used and you aren't changing what you have read from the file before writing it back out, so your current code will have no noticeable effect on the file.

Comment: @CryptoFool What I wanted to do was to execute a program, let's call it "test.py", from IDLE's terminal, the program would change the value of a variable, then at the end change the value written in the same program, "test.py" (so `test = 45` becomes `test = 50`). I know my code is shit, I'm still learning, but my question was why couldn't I save this code as a python file.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with IDLE.  It is not even really a Python question as your operating system will respond to a C program that does the same opens, reads, writes, and closes.  With Python 3.12.0b2 on Windows, the code in the question runs without error.  What OS are you using?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy The steps I used to recreate this are 1. Open a new file in Python IDLE 3.8.5. 2. Copy the code into the file. 3. Save the file/ Run the file. 4. Close the file, and then reopen it (it should be blank). 5. Then copy the same code (and if the name is different change the name). From this, you should not be able to save the file.
I tested the code on Python IDLE 3.11.1 and did the steps above and the file did save, so it does have something to do with Python IDLE 3.8.5. My OS is Windows 11 Home, Version 21H2, OS Build 22000.1335.

Comment: The final bugfix version of 3.8 is 3.8.10, release in May 2021.  In any case, thank you for testing with 3.11.1 to confirm that there is no problem with current python/idle.

Answer (score 0):

you have to be more clear when you say it won't let you save!
but you open the file in write only mode first which truncate and overwrite the file, so when you are reading it it would be empty file.
so if you wanna fix your code , you have to open the file in read only mode first then open it in write mode only :

```
with open("test file change in file.py", "r") as read:
    file = read.read()
with open("test file change in file.py", "w") as write:
    write.write(file)
```

seems like you want to edit a file.You just need to open it in `r+` (read and write) mode :

```
with open('filename.txt' ,'r+') as f:
    text = f.read()               # read the text file
    text = text.replace('Y', 'X') # edit the text 
    f.seek(0)                     # go back to the beginning of the file 
    f.write(text)                 # save the changes
```

Comment: I didn't know 'r+' opens a file in read and write mode. However, my code wasn't my problem. My question was why my code could not be saved as a python file.

Comment: Your original answer did fix my code, but my question wasn't "Why isn't my code working?" It was "Why isn't my code saving?" This has something to do with either my OS or IDLE itself, and that's why I'm asking

Comment: @nikolamarkoski see my explanation for the reason your code was not working